# Force serialization as base type

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

I'm struggling with MongoDB and getting the serialization to work the way I want it to.

I have a solution/project structure similar to this:

- Core, which contains commonly known entities, but no business logic, and is referenced by all other projects.
- Repository, which handles persistence of entities (defined in Core). Contains various methods for persistence, including one using MongoDB.
- Project A, has a reference to Core and Repository.
- Poject B, also with references to Core and Repository.

Project A and B has no references to each other, and they should be oblivous to the fact the Repository is using MongoDB for persistence.

In Core, I've defined a type, `Package`, with a property, `Items`, which is an array of `Item`.

In Project A I am extending `Item` via inheritance. I can persist instances of `Package`, including instances of the extended `Item`, via the Repository.

However, things fall apart when Project B then tries to retrieve a `Package` created by Project A, because the extended `Item` is unknown to Project B. The deserialization fails.

Ideally, when Project B loads a `Package`, the `Items` array would just be instances of the base `Item`.

**Idea:** I think the solution I'm looking for is simply forcing Repository to always use the base type from Core when persisting the extended `Item`. **How do I do that?** Project A has other means of converting the `Item` back to an instance of the extended version if necessary.

I’ve tried tweaking the serialization, so the _t is always set to the discriminator of the base class from Core. But this causes an exception during deserialization, as there are multiple types mapped to that discriminator.

Comment: It looks a bit strange that you 1) extend domain entities (defined in Core) in Project A and then persist them, 2) try to load the extended entities in Project B. I guess you can solve an _initial_ problem different way instead of its consequence. So please give more details about 1) and 2) why do you have to do so